# Did Iran host anti Soviet Afghan factions during the 1980's?

Tags: iran, afghanistan

It is well known that Pakistan hosted many anti-Soviet Sunni fundamentalist groups, who continue to generate problems for Pakistan (and the world) to this day.

If Iran did  provide sanctuary to anti-Soviet Afghan factions, they  most likely would have come from Afghanistan's Shiite minority refugees. On the other hand, I suspect Iran would have maintained a hands off policy in this conflict in light of its war with Iraq at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Iran called for a Soviet withdrawal and aided Afghan Shiites. In the second phase, after the Soviet Army withdrew, Iran helped the non-Pushtun ethnic groups form a united front.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **yes**. To quote from on [an article](http://scholarcommons.usf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1106&context=gia_facpub) you may want to look at:

> The essence of Iran's policy toward Afghanistan was to create an
>   "ideological sphere of influence" by mobilizing and energizing
>   the Afghan Shi'ites, which comprised about 20% of the population,
>   while barely dealing with the Communist government of
>   Afghanistan.  Tehran's Shi'i-centered and parochial policy
>   transformed the historically oppressed and marginalized Hazaras,
>   Qizilbash, and Farsiwans Shi'ites into a disciplined and cohesive
>   force. Tehran provided financial support to the Shi'ites, gave
>   them hope, trained a generation of activists, and established
>   close links with the Afghan 'ulama'. The presence of Afghan
>   refugees in Iran provided Tehran with a unique opportunity to
>   train an indigenous Afghan force that was to be relocated to
>   Afghanistan at the opportune moment... Iran's investments paid
>   off when the eight Iran-based Afghan-Shi'i groups formed an
>   alliance in June of 1987.

This resulting "alliance" of Shia mujahadeen was known as the [Tehran Eight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tehran_Eight) and formally dissolved in 1989.